# Key code checker for Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I use synergy for sharing keyboard/mouse on my mac/pc.

I need to switch the alt(option) key mapping to meta, and I need some tool if this works.

What kind of tool is used for checking the key code that is send when I hit the key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply create a HTML to do so.

1. Copy & paste the following code into a new HTML file, say `keycode.html`.
2. Open it with a browser.
3. Press a key. A prompt with key code would appear.

---

```
<html>

<script>
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) keycode = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) keycode = e.which;
    alert(keycode);
}
</script>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with exactly same case!

HTML checker by @wilson is working just fine with two little exceptions: it doesn't capture **fn** nor **power** (which actually what I want to make use of)

Found on the internet (using AutoHotKey)

```
;-----------------------------------------
; Mac keyboard to Windows Key Mappings
;=========================================

; 1) Swap Windows (Command) and Alt keys
; These button locations are reversed on Mac keyboards

LAlt::LCtrl
LCtrl::LAlt

; 2) Map F13 to Print screen
; Mac keyboards don't have a print-screen button!

F13::PrintScreen
```

(F13 in my case doesn't work, clipboard remains empty)
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Maybe there is a way to read keycode and send it using these codes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

*(my case is even more complicated as I'm using polish layout and there is another layer of complexity with diacritic marks)*

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [KeyboardStateView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/keyboard_state_view.html)

It indicates the details of each key stroke live, including:

- Key Name
- Description
- Key Code
- Hex Key Code
- Whether it was pressed
- Whether it was toggled

[image]

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Online tool: [keycode.info](https://keycode.info/)

1. Visit https://keycode.info/
2. Press any key to get the keycode