How to bind alt+` in Windows terminal on U.S. keyboard layout?
I am running a machine with both Danish and English (U.S.) layout.
In my settings.json I have the following:
{
    "command":
    {
        "action": "quakeMode"
    },
    "keys": "alt+½"
},
{
    "command":
    {
        "action": "quakeMode"
    },
    "keys": "alt+`"
}

I have added this code, but only when I am on Danish keyboard layout do the quakeMode launch, so the ` is not the correct character to add when using english U.S. layout?

Perhaps knowing the keycode would help: https://superuser.com/questions/189065/key-code-checker-for-windows

Tried setting it to "keys": "alt+\u0060" from https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm but that didnt work while on danish layout "keys": "alt+\u00bd" works just fine
